# Pandas Changing the format of NaN values when saving to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I am working with a df and using numpy to transform data - including setting blanks (or '') to NaN. But when I write the df to csv - the output contains the string 'nan' as oppose to being NULL.

I have looked around but can't find a workable solution. Here's the basic issue:

```
df
index x    y   z
0     1   NaN  2
1     NaN  3   4
```

CSV output:

```
index x    y   z
0     1   nan  2
1     nan  3   4
```

I have tried a few things to set 'nan' to NULL but the csv output results in a 'blank' rather than NULL:

```
dfDemographics = dfDemographics.replace('nan', np.NaN)
dfDemographics.replace(r'\s+( +\.)|#', np.nan, regex=True).replace('', 
np.nan)
dfDemographics = dfDemographics.replace('nan', '')  # of course, this wouldn't work, but tried it anyway.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 68):

Pandas to the rescue, use `na_rep` to fix your own representation for NaNs.

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='NULL')
```

`file.csv`

```
,index,x,y,z
0,0,1.0,NULL,2
1,1,NULL,3.0,4
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need - this replaces NA in df with a string of 'NULL'. I realize my post may not be clear - by NULL I meant - nothing. That is the NaN, in the csv output, should be just nothing - no strings, no data, including spaces.

Comment: @Jerry What about `df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='')`?

Comment: @Jerry That's the default behaviour of `to_csv` actually, you are probably doing something else wrong but I don't see how it is possible to get the output from the input you posted. https://imgur.com/3xNP5aG

Comment: @user2285236 - I believe you are correct - this shouldn't happen; something else is going on in the script, most likely with my use of numpy (np.select). Will keep at it.

Comment: @Jerry "something else is probably going on" and what might that be? Your question as it stands is unanswerable. Should we close it?

Comment: @CallCentreExecutive - I have investigated without success to resolve this issue. The question remains unanswered. Per your note, you are welcome to close the question.

Comment: in my case this quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC was causing the quoting of the NULL

Answer (score 4):

Using df.replace may help -

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
```

(This sets all the null values to '' i.e empty string.)

Comment: Thanks - but no luck here either. Something else is probably going on.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want on the end .csv file for Nan values, like do you want them to be null or what? I'm not able to understand. @Jerry

Comment: the NaN in csv output should be just that - nothing. For some reason, some of the columns in the df with NaN are being written as either 'nan' (as a string) or just '' (empty string). The problem is most likely arising during the data transformation process, probably with my use of np.select.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, the culprit was `np.where`. When the data types of the two return elements are different, then your `np.NaN` will be converted to a `nan`.

It's hard (for me) to see exactly what's going on under the hood, but I suspect this might be true for other Numpy array methods that have mixed types.

A minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, np.NaN]
same_type_seq = np.where("parrot"=="dead", 0, seq)
diff_type_seq = np.where("parrot"=="dead", "spam", seq)

pd.Series(seq).to_csv("vanilla_nan.csv", header=False) # as expected, last row is blank
pd.Series(same_type_seq).to_csv("samey_nan.csv", header=False) # also, blank
pd.Series(diff_type_seq).to_csv("nany_nan.csv", header=False) # nan instead of blank
```

So how to get round this? I'm not too sure, but as a hacky workaround for small datasets, you can replace `NaN` in your original sequence with a token string and then replace it back to `np.NaN`

```
repl = "missing"
hacky_seq = np.where("parrot"=="dead", "spam", [repl if np.isnan(x) else x for x in seq])
pd.Series(hacky_seq).replace({repl:np.NaN}).to_csv("hacky_nan.csv", header=False)
```

Comment: Everything that is not a string is coerced to a string to avoid having mixed types in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on gherka's and Kranthi Kiran's answers:

```
df = df.replace("nan", '', regex=True)
df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think someone posted this already but you turned it down due to showing the 'NULL' string in the file:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='NULL')
```

Now I understand you want an actual blank value there. CSVs are text files, the blank text is just the empty stting '', so the solution is to use that instead:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='')
```

This works for me. Some other solutions may still be valid, but this is by far the simplest and most straightforward. If this was a fixed width file, you would have to replace with spaces however wide that field was, but for csv you don't need the spaces, just the empty string.

PS: I would have made a comment on the other user's response, but I'm a new user therefore not allowed to post comments yet... that said, any upvotes appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

User @coldspeed illustrates how to replace nan values with NULL when save pd.DataFrame. In case, for data analysis, one is interested in replacing the "NULL" values in pd.DataFrame with np.NaN values, the following code will do:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

# replace NULL values with np.nan
colNames = mydf.columns.tolist()
dfVals = mydf.values
matSyb = mydf.isnull().values
dfVals[matSyb] = np.NAN

mydf = pd.DataFrame(dfVals, columns=colNames)    
#np.nansum(mydf.values, axis=0 )
#np.nansum(dfVals, axis=0 )
```